# What's the difference between pandas.isna and numpy.isnan?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I checked docs of [pandas isna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [numpy isnan](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html).

They seemed to say that `numpy.isnan` detects *NaN* only and `pandas.isna` detects both *NaN* and *None* type.

Is that so?

Comment: `pd.isna` is defined in `pd.core.dtypes.missing.py`.  It checks more things.  `np.isnan` only works on numeric dtype arrays.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this is correct.
`np.isnan` checks if your value is `np.nan` or your iterable (array,list) contains `np.nan`.
For example (from their documentation):
`np.isnan([np.log(-1.),1.,np.log(0)])` results `array([ True, False, False])` this is because np.log(-1) is not defined and results `np.nan`. `np.isnan` does not detects python None.

`pandas.isna` on the other hand lays above numpy and detects both `np.nan` and None values.